# Use Python Element Tree to parse xml in ASCII text file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have ASCII text files that contain XML sections in them. I try the following basic commands to open the file, but get an error:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data_file.txt')
```

Is there a way I can still use Element Tree to be able to parse the XML sections out of the text file?

Comment: First you have to dissect the text from the XML. Then you can separately process each XML part.

Comment: Why don't you share what the error is. It may be helpful or something.

Comment: I'll wager that it will be an instance of `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError`. See my answer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ElementTree to parse a file that isn't in its entirety well-formed XML. If there is text content before or after the root element of the XML document, XML parsing will fail, as it will if there are any other infractions against well-formedness.

More generally, standards-compliant XML parsers can parse only well-formed XML. So your scenario is actually fairly common.

One approach would be to write a program that processes the file and attempts to find the XML embedded in the other content, and that handles that part of the file with ElementTree. If your XML content is simple, this is quite feasible. If it's complex, or if there is more than one XML document embedded in the text file, it gets a little more challenging, but it may still be doable.