# Parse ASCII Text file containing XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, file-io

I have an ASCII text file that contains XML sections in them. The file structure is as follows:

```
text...
text...
<note1>
   <date>2015-09-01</date>
   <hour>08:30</hour>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note1>
text...
text...
   <note2>
   <date>2015-09-01</date>
   <hour>08:30</hour>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note2>
text...
text...
```

How can I go about stepping through the file and locating the XML portions and use `ElementTree`, or anything else easier to store the XML sections into their own XML file? So file 1 would be `file1.xml` with the following content:

```
<note1>
   <date>2015-09-01</date>
   <hour>08:30</hour>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note1>
```

Then file 2 would be `file2.xml` with the following content:

```
<note2>
   <date>2015-09-01</date>
   <hour>08:30</hour>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note2>
```

Comment: FYI: This is an (extended and improved) version of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48131838/1305969). It would be great to find a suitable solution for dissecting the text from the XML parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup can do a great job in processing malformed XML. Here you could simply do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(textfilename) as fd:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fd)

n1 = soup.findChild()         # extract first full XML element, here <node1>...</node1>
while n1:
    # process the XML element
    ...
    n1 = n1.findNextSibling() # extract next full XML element
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that with ElementTree? I don't have BS, and it will take me forever to get it on my work PC....

Comment: @DeeTee: If I correctly remember, ET requires well formed XML, so you will have to skip over text which is not in XML blocks, as proposed in Jake's answer. The point of BS is that it identifies the XML blocks without you to code that part.

Comment: It seems like the approach provided above requires you to know the number of elements the file needs to have. I have an arbitrary number of elements, the two provided in the example was for the sake of simplicity. Is there a way BS can ID all elements in the file?

Comment: @DeeTee: The `while n1:` will loop over all XML blocks, whatever the number (and will no choke if none at all)

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be something like this..

First, open the file with the in-built python [file handler](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python). This will allow you to read, write, and create new text files. You just need to name new files `file#.xml` to save it as an xml file.

Second, you iterate through the target file line by line and search for `<>` the start of xml code. You would also want to store the value of the string contained within the tag. As you proceed from here you start writing every line to a new xml file. Then every time you find `<>` in the file you check for the string value that initiated the search. You may also want to verify if has the closing tag indicator `/`. Once you hit the closing tag and add it you are done with the first xml file.

You proceed to search for `<>` and basically repeat the second step and create a new xml file. You do this for the entire input file.

The downside to this naive implementation is that if your normal text contains a set of `<>` it may cause errors. Also initial and final xml tags for each file must be well formed.

I don't think there is need to store the xml data in an `ElementTree`.